# SMO.Transfer fails due to LocalAdmin login, but only for some databases

Tags: sql-server, smo

I am attempting to copy an SQL Server database into a new database on the same server without transferring the data (that is, I'm trying to build an identical, empty database).

The code below works correctly on a sample database that I built specifically for testing.  But when applied to the actual target database, it fails at the `.TransferData()` call (after several seconds of execution) with the error `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : 'LocalAdmin' is not a valid login or you do not have permission.`  The account under which I'm developing and testing program can be used to log into the SQL Server instance in question and perform database creation, and creation of objects within both the source and target databases.

After the failure, the database specified in targetDb *has*, in fact, been created, but it has no tables or other structures.

Can anyone tell me how to fix the following code so that it will be able to successfully copy my database structure?

```
/* Ref: Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
        Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll
        Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll */

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CopyEmptyDatabase(@"server_name\instance_name", "sourceDb_name", "targetDb_name");
        }

        public static void CopyEmptyDatabase(string instance, string sourceDb, string targetDb)
        {
            var server = new Server(instance);

            var transferAgent = new Transfer(server.Databases[sourceDb]);

            transferAgent.CopyAllObjects = true;
            transferAgent.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;
            transferAgent.CopySchema = true;
            transferAgent.CopyData = false;

            // Transfer requires the target DB to exist
            var target = new Database(server, targetDb);
            target.Create();

            transferAgent.DestinationServer = instance;
            transferAgent.DestinationDatabase = targetDb;
            transferAgent.DestinationLoginSecure = true;
            transferAgent.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;

            try
            {
                transferAgent.TransferData();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Debug.Print(exc.Message);
                throw;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create the new database what login and user are you using to add the schemas?

Comment: Also as SSMS has scripts that make this entire process a snap. Right click on the database in your project Explorer select generate Scripts and check to add all the relevant objects for everything. There is an option to include schema and metadata but by default it is set to just your schematics

Comment: No repro. Your code works fine for me.

Comment: @MartinSmith Works fine for me on the sample database I created to test against.  Just the "actual" database that fails.

Comment: The answer is still a permissions issue. Perhaps you might find it better...and even safer...to seperate the application into write and read operations. One recreates the script into an encrypted hashed file/variable and another that reads the hash into SQLCMD. This way, you can either just create a login and user (note the hash password via sp_help_revlogin) with privileges to create a database and then read the script or run it from a legitimate sysadmin account via Windows Authenticate. multiple ways but the error code suggest the service account the app runs under lacks permissions.

Comment: Larry were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Mandi Yes, that program is running.  However, it's been so long that I don't remember what the solution was.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a new db from the SQL tools and see if you can drop the sprocs that are in the newly created db. If you're not the `dbo`, you probably won't have permissions to drop them. Note that the objects therein are copied from the `model` db...so it won't be completely empty at the start. Your organization may have added things to the `model` as well...so you'll need to look into that.

**Edit**:

Another way to test this theory...just remove the line that says `transferAgent.DropDestinationObjectsFirst = true;`

Answer (score 0):

- Login issues may be related to the service account that the query runs under. For example, replication uses the SQL Server Agent account by default to read into a fileshare. This also relates to what account is attempting to login to the target database.
- never write in plain text passwords.
- ensure the SUSER_ID is the same as logically, two identical but plain text login/users will be distinct from each other.

Try not to reinvent the wheel when it already is available to you. Unless this is an application (sounds risky), utilizing the tools you already possess will save time, create stable `.sql` files, and help control your changes to any PROD environments.

As a general rule, if I change anything on the schematics level for a PROD server, I save the script or prior schematics before implementing it. You never know when it can save your life.

1. Use SSMS and select GENERATE SCRIPTS
   [image: Generate Scripts]
   In your `Object Explorer`, right click on the target database. Under the tab `Tasks`, select `Generate Scripts...`

   - By default, the settings are set to recreate all major (`tables`, `schemas`, `Stored Procedures`, etc) objects, but this does not include some intangible settings such as the data.
2. Set location
   [image: Set Scripting Options]
   Set the location of your scripts, such as a shared folder that everyone can find.

   - If you can avoid `Unicode` scripts, use the `ANSI` setting, as any large `.sql` files will require `SQLCMD` to execute.
   - Alternately, you can split the objects into their own files, to allow for *version control*.
3. Use the Advanced Settings
   [image: Set the environment]
   You can set the version level of your scripts (as far back as `SQL Server 2005`) and the type of database engine.

   - You will be to specify **Logins**, **Object-Level Permissions**, **Owners**, and can even optionally include **Statistics** and their **Histograms** if your tests are the same as your PROD environment. IN general, let the Optimizer handle this.
   - Other objects, such as `Triggers`, may not be included, so be sure to go through the list for your environment.
4. Enjoy your new .sql scripts!
   [image: Enjoy!!!]
   That's all!

> The best part is this used the native `SSMS` client to create and you
>   have legitimate `.sql` files that any SQL Server edition will be able to
>   read.

Comment: Thank you.  As should be clear from the code this is, in fact, an application.

Comment: @Larry.Lustig be as it may, it is perhaps foolish to design such a thing. First, the application would need next to sysadmin rights and even then how would one prevent this from being abused? Your not wrong in your assessment in theory, and i did address this at the beginning.

Comment: This is an internal utility to allow us to obfuscate databases to make them safe for development within our organization.  I certainly don't intend to store credentials in the application, either in plain text or otherwise.  If the Windows log in under which the utility is run is not sufficient to provide credentials necessary to complete `.TransferData()` then I'm happy to have the user enter transient credentials as part of the utility.

Comment: I guess my question boils down to: What default credentials does SMO use when I attempt `.TransferData()` on a remote instance of SQL Server, and how can I set the credentials to user-supplied ones if necessary.